# QUdpSocket не принимает пакеты на windows

Tags: qt, сокет, qt5

```
Вот код 
udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this); 
groupAddress = QHostAddress("239.255.43.21");
if(!udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4), portMulti,  QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint|QUdpSocket::ShareAddress)) {
   qDebug() <<"Бида все пропало1";
}
if(!udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress)) {
   qDebug() <<"Бида все пропало2";
}
connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));
```

На linux этот код работает без проблем но на windows работает только если впишу и в сервер и в клиент внутренний ip адрес сервера (192.158.0.102 ну или там что типа того вы поняли) если я вписываю другие ip ничего не работает, скажите чтоя делаю не так, как это исправить пожалуйста. Очень надо.
Кидаю код с андроида-клиента может кто то надоумит что нетак, я без понятия почему оно толькона Linuxe работает.

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(/*45454*/);
  socket.setBroadcast(true);
 InetAddress groupAddr = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.43.21"); //на этом (выдуманный) работает только на linux
 //InetAddress groupAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.102"); //на этом адресе работает
  byte[] outbuf = makeStartPacket();
  sendPacket(socket, groupAddr, outbuf);



private byte[] makeStartPacket() { byte[] outPack = ("Ляляля").getBytes(); return outPack; } private void sendPacket(DatagramSocket socket, InetAddress groupAddr, byte[] outbuf) throws IOException { DatagramPacket packet; packet = new DatagramPacket(outbuf, outbuf.length, groupAddr, /9901//2425//multiPort/45455); //outbuf = createLegacyDiscoveryRequest(socket); socket.send(packet);
```

---

Проблема найдена, но очень нужно решение. Беда в том что я устанавливал genymotion, genymotion устанавливал virtualbox, virtualbox устанавливал еще сетевые адаптары интерфейсы ну короче Центр управления сетями и общим доступом->Изменения параметра адаптеров, туда добавлялись + 2 адаптора. Когда я тестил без этих адаптеров, или на linux, то сервер видимо подкл. к 1 сетевому интерфейсу правильному, как то так. Но когда их стало много, случилась ошибка. Но как же теперь, это все исправить, пробовал подкл интерфейсы пока не помогает, да и какой подключать? Надо же правильный,короче надо решение код, с обходом этой проблемы. Заранее огромнейшее спс если кто поможет.

Comment: Ну наверно на Windows брандмауэр блокирует соединение.

Comment: Отключен брандмауэр.

Comment: Раз у вас есть внутренний IP, значит есть средства маршрутизации?

Comment: Ну я имел ввиду Wifi роутер. Т.е. у меня смартфон на андроид на андроид и комп в 1 wifi сети. Вобщем отзывается все только на внутренний ip компьютера из моей wi-fi сети (192.168.0.102). брандмауэр откл. Может еще что откл. надо. Спс за ответ 3 день сижу ничего не пойму. Еще идея сперва когда проверял брандмауэр был вкл., я его сразу откл. когда не заработало, но результата 0 (

Comment: Еще такое чуство что вот это вот udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress); до лампочки, да возвращает оно true, но например когда я его удаляю или не удаляю все равно если в андроид клиент ставить InetAddress groupAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.102") работает, но если InetAddress groupAddr = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.43.21") не работает в любом случае, но пакеты на комп приходят я whirelshark устанавливал проверял.

Comment: А попробуйте пробросить порты на роутере... Мне кажется, что проблема в этом.

Comment: Хотя странно, что на пингвине работает, а на окошках нет....

Comment: Открывал порты я на роутере, не помогает. + проверил на Windows 8.1 и Window 7, вроде работает, походу что то не то с 10 и с роутером тоже интернет что то подрезает. Буду пока на 8.1 и 7 ориентирыватся ну а то потом.

Comment: Короче у меня вот эта вот эта вот [беда](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49072-UDP-socket-doesn-t-receive-packets)
А вобще интерестно, ничего не известно все у всех работает странно. Вот тебе и qt :(

Comment: похоже, Вам нужно биндиться на правильный интерфейс. скорее всего нужно просто указать правильный апйи здесь `if(!udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4)`

Comment: Не это я уже давно пробовал непомогает. И вот это тоже походу до лампочки udpSocket->setMulticastInterface не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Вот код 
            udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this); 
            groupAddress = QHostAddress("255.255.255.255");
            if(!udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4), portMulti,  QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint|QUdpSocket::ShareAddress)) {
               qDebug() <<"Бида все пропало1";
            }
            if(!udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress)) {
               qDebug() <<"Бида все пропало2";
            }
    udpSocket->setMulticastInterface( getNetworkInterfaceByAddress("192.168.0.102") );
            connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));

    QNetworkInterface getNetworkInterfaceByAddress(QString adr)
        {
            QList<QNetworkInterface> il(QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces());
            for (int i = 0; i < il.size(); i++)
            {
                QList<QNetworkAddressEntry> ade(il[i].addressEntries());
                for (int j = 0; j < ade.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (ade[j].ip().toString() == adr)
                        return il[i];
                }
            }

            return QNetworkInterface();
        }
```

Вот решение, но увы почему то работает у меня только с 255.255.255.255 , хотя я естественно не все ip перебрал, если кто знает почему то напишите, пока буду писать так. Короче надо правильный интерфейс добавить было и походу правильный выдуманный ip Да кстати ф-я getNetworkInterfaceByAddress(QString adr) вроде рабочая но смысл в том что я написал сверху.